# Um .CSS para "Above the Fold" e outro .CSS para "Below the fold" - Vale a pena?

Tags: css, desempenho

Em questão de performance e manutenibilidade seria interessante ter 2 arquivos de `css` na página, um para o conteúdo que aparece antes da dobra e outro para o conteúdo que aparece após a dobra?

Tipo:

```
 <link href="above.css"> (20kb)
--------------------------------
 <link href="below.css"> (200kb)
```

Como as requisições são de forma linear a renderização da parte superior seria mais rápida correto? O usuário veria a página sendo montada mais rapidamente acredito, mas como fica o carregamento do segundo `.css`. Quando começar o carregamento do `below.css` por exemplo ele pode interferir nas imagens que serão carregadas na parte superior da dobra? Ou será montado primeiro 100% da parte superior e só depois começa o carregamento da parte inferior?

Já que serão feitas duas requisições eu posso perder performance ou seria completamente irrelevante?

Ou seria melhor ***minificar*** tudo em uma folha de estilo só `style.css` *(above.css + below.css)* e pronto?

Answer (score 0):

Com base em suas dúvidas, eu acredito que a melhor solução levando em conta a performance, seria colocar todo o código em um único arquivo e depois minificar o mesmo. Claro que mantendo sempre uma cópia não minificada como backup para futuras alterações no código.

Agora a questão de dividir o código em dois ou mais arquivos, particularmente eu acho mais organizado. Porém é preciso atentar muito bem para não começar a misturar os códigos que deveriam ficar separados quando houver alguma alteração a se fazer.

Com relação a fazer mais de uma requisição para trazer varios arquivos pode haver sim perda de performance, dependendo do tamanho dos arquivos .css da mesma forma que pode acontecer com arquivos .html ou .js também. Mas acaba sendo um pouco relativa essa questão pois vai depender muito da conexão do usuário na hora de baixar os arquivos.