# A ordem dos estilos CSS influenciam a árvore de renderização?

Tags: html, css, dom

Durante o *paint* do documento pelo browser a ordem das propriedades das classes do CSS podem interferir em como percebemos a "montagem" da página?

Principalmente em conexões mais lentas, literalmente vemos os estilos sendo aplicados aos elementos, então a ordem das propriedades que usamos nas classes deve ser algo a se levar em consideração ao escrever o CSS? Digo, a ordem dos atributos nas classes interfere no CSSOM e como a Árvore de Renderização é construída pelo browser?

Vi essa imagem e fiquei me questionando se a ordem dos estilos do CSS pode interferir no *paint* da página...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo:** *(considerando a árvore de renderização/conexões lentas/performance e UX/UI)*

Digamos que temos o seguinte CSS que foi escrito "aleatoriamente" sem preocupação alguma com os atributos.

```
.container {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: consola;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

E temos outro CSS que foi escrito pensando na ordem que o layout dos elementos é construído:

```
.container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    font-family: consola;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

***Deve haver um cuidado na ordem desses atributos dentro das classes, eles influenciam em como acontece a Árvore de Renderização e o paint da página? Existe alguma boa prática?***

***Quais atributos são mais importantes que os outros no CSS e quais são interpretados com prioridade ou não?***

*Ou isso não existe, é totalmente irrelevante e não se deve perder tempo com isso?*

**OBS:** Sei que muito provavelmente cada browser pode entender isso de uma forma diferente, então não faço distinção sobre um navegador ou outro ok, qualquer informação é válida.

Comment: A ordem que você das propriedades de uma classe não vai importar na hora de renderizar, o DOM libera seu nó quando tudo for aplicado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com o artigo
[Quantum Up Close: What is a browser engine?](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/05/quantum-up-close-what-is-a-browser-engine/), o mecanismo do navegador lê toda a folha de estilo CSS para então, finalmente, usar a *style engine* e pegar o CSS para aplicar ao DOM que foi criado pelo *HTML parser*.

Então uma interpretação superficial, sem levar em conta nuances do desenvolvimento de um navegador em específico, seria que o navegador usa o *CSS parser* na folha de estilo por completa e, somente no fim do processo de *parse*, utiliza a *style engine*.

Então, **não**. Não há consequências mediante a ordenação aleatória de propriedades CSS.

Contudo, mesmo que não afete a performance do projeto de forma significativa, deve-se atentar a organização desse fragmento do projeto, com o objetivo de facilitar a leitura da folha. Eis alguns artigos sobre o tema:

[“Outside In” — Ordering CSS Properties by Importance - Tutsplus](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/outside-in-ordering-css-properties-by-importance--cms-21685)

[6 Estratégias para melhorar a organização do seu CSS - Tableless](https://tableless.com.br/6-estrategias-para-melhorar-a-organizacao-do-seu-css-2/)

De acordo com a pesquisa divulgada pelo CSS Tricks, a maioria dos desenvolvedores utilizam a estratégia de organização por tipo.

Por exemplo: Propriedade *width* junto da propriedade *height* por ambas especificarem dimensões.

Além do agrupamento por tipo, há também a técnica utilizada pelo escritor do artigo do Tutsplus: o "Outside In".

O método consiste basicamente em ordenar o CSS de "dentro para fora", por isso o nome.

Por exemplo: Propriedades como *position*, *float* e *display* controlam o fluxo dos elementos na página e isso afeta também outros elementos ao redor. Então, de acordo com o autor, esse tipo de propriedade deve vir primeiro. E, por fim, propriedades como *cursor* e *z-index*, que afetam somente o elemento em questão, devem aparecer.

A ordem optada pelo autor é:

- Propriedades do layout (*position*, *float*, *clear*, *display*)
- Propriedades de modelagem (*width*, *height*, *margin*, *padding*)
- Propriedades visuais (*color*, *background*, *border*, *box-shadow*)
- Propriedades tipográficas (*font-size*, *font-family*, *text-align*,
  *text-transform*)
- Outras propriedades (*cursor*, *overflow*, *z-index*)

Comment: Cara bem interessante esse artigo do Tutsplus, pegue alguns exemplo que ele usa lá e coloca ai na sua resposta para dar uma enriquecida nela, acho que a comunidade vai gostar!

Comment: @hugocsl, adicionei os exemplos. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 8):

Eu já havia me feito essa pergunta antes :)

Nessa pergunta similar do SO, as respostas dizem que não: [Are there speed benefits of putting CSS attributes in alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34158386/4730201)

Embora não tenha nada embasado em uma documentação ou link oficial, acredito que realmente não afete a performance na renderização da página.

Um fato concreto que me faz acreditar nisso, é que ferramentas de organização de `CSS` (como o [CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/)) tem a opção de formatar e ordenar as declarações, o que, se houvesse mesmo uma priorização, seria um grande erro permitir organizar.

No site css-tricks, há um post com uma pesquisa sobre como as pessoas constumar organizar o seu CSS quanto a declaração dos atributos, e também não há nada mencionando o tempo de renderização segundo a ordem dos atributos: [poll results: how do you order your css properties/](https://css-tricks.com/poll-results-how-do-you-order-your-css-properties/)

Não é conclusivo, mas baseado nessas respostas, e em como as ferramentas de otimização se comportam ao tratar os arquivos de estilo, acredito que realmente não exista uma diferença na renderização ou no processamento da árvore de acordo com a ordem que os atributos são declarados.

Answer (score 7):

Interessante tópico, sempre acreditei que a ordem não influenciaria porém ajudaria numa leitura de código.

No Tableless, [tem um artigo um pouco antigo](https://tableless.com.br/6-estrategias-para-melhorar-a-organizacao-do-seu-css-2/) não fala de performance mas sugere algumas boas práticas e inclusive fala de ordenação lógica dos parâmetros.

Pensando em organização eu sigo a lógica pensando no bloco de fora pra dentro e finalizo com detalhes, bordas, transitions etc.

```
.seletor {
    [posicionamento]
    [tamanho]
    [espaçamentos]
    [fonte e propriedades de texto]
    [plano de fundo]
    [bordas]
    [outros]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu havia me feito a mesma pergunta a alguns tempos atrás, e fui procurar pelo que entendi o que pode influenciar em relação ao carregamento e "peso da pagina" no geral são "funções / desenhos" de elementos direto no CSS e CSS muito grades, por exemplo:

- Criar uma animação dentro do CSS
- Fazer um CSS cheio de má praticas
  (Colocando todo style de todas as páginas em um único arquivo fazendo com que o mesmo ocupe um grande tamanho e precise ser carregado em todas paginas)

Um exemplo imagine uma class(css) que só é chamada no index.html

mas na pagina2.html você carregou o mesmo css, sua class fica inutilizada "pesando" sem necessidade.

## Boas Praticas

Em boas praticas os CSS e JS's são divididos para cada tipo de necessidade abaixo temos um exemplo de CSS com boas praticas (Template retirado do site https://br.yahoo.com/ )
[image: Em boas praticas os CSS são divididos para cada tipo de necessidade abaixo temos um exemplo de CSS com boas praticas, retirado do site https://br.yahoo.com/]
executando códigos dessa maneira sua aplicação no geral não ficara lerda mesmo em conexões de baixa latência, pois cada style está separado pra sua determinada pasta de origem e necessidade.

Você também pode dar uma olhada no que influencia o load da pagina nesse link :
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30439/what-influences-the-loading-of-a-web-page

Comment: Mt legal! Mudando pra JS, o que vc acha melhor: colocar o código direto na página ou carregar um .js? Ou tanto faz?

Comment: Vai depender do que esse código precisa fazer, eu acredito que montar uma função de 3~4 linhas dentro do próprio elemento HTML não seja ruim ou "errado"(não está errado mas não é uma boa prática), sempre que possível tente criar .JS ... Claro que você não vai criar um .JS pra uma função que pode ser feita inline. **Imagine** assim: outra pessoa quer ver seu código pra utilizar algo que achou interessante ou para fazer uma manutenção no seu código, o que é mais fácil (   )Ir nos arquivos referenciados ou  (   )procurar dentro de todo scopo do HTML os códigos inline/block?

Comment: >> vale a pena dar uma olhada : https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/conteudo/artigos/informatica/boas-praticas-para-desenvolvimento-de-websites-otimizados/16093

Comment: Esse é um ponto interessante! Já até havia abordado ele em uma outra questão, mas digamos que nessa questão o tratamento do CSS seria ainda mais "refinado", separando o CSS que está na primeira dobra da página do CSS que vem depois da dobra. (Ex, imagine ter uma folha de estilo pro menu, header, etc, e outro css para o footer e tudo que só venha lá no final do documento) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291116/um-css-para-above-the-fold-e-outro-css-para-below-the-fold-vale-a-pena . Com relação a ordem das propriedades dentro da classe vc teria alguma dica de boa prática ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @Gunblades então, como a outra pergunta foi fechada, considere aproveitar o conteúdo dela nessa questão por exemplo, ou alguma outra aqui do site que esteja ligada a esse assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65783/boas-pr%C3%A1ticas-usando-css e aqui tem uma lista mais completa boas práticas css pt.stackoverflow site:pt.stackoverflow.com veja o melhor lugar que vc encontra pra usar o conteúdo